# Cross-region access to database on AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have created a database(postgres) on AWS in region1. Now I want a developer from region2 to help me on the database located in region1.

I know AWS as default do not permit cross-region access. But is it possible to give access to the database for the developer in region2? If yes, how?

Comment: What is the purpose of the developer access? Is it to execute queries? Or is it for a deployment of the same web server in another region to access a replication of the database?

Comment: Its for writing and testing stored procedures

Comment: Not enough information here. Is this RDS? Is it running in VPC? Is the RDS instance in a private subnet or is it publicly available? When you say "a developer from region2", can you elaborate on why you think that's relevant?

Comment: It was for inviting a developer from another region to change a script in a dabase. After working with it a couple of days, I tested google cloud. Took me less than 10 min to get him access. Doing it in Google, you need the external IP's, and plot them in. Its a bit of a problem with people having dynamic IP's, but it works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Do as below:
- On region1: follow [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html) to public you RDS
- On region2: add NAT for your VPC to make internet accessing.
So I illustrate the flow as: 
[region2: `your_app` -> `NAT`] ---(internet)--> [region1: `Internet_gateway` -> `bastion_instance (optional)` -> `RDS`]

With newly update, you can also use `AWS Direct Connect Gateway` to connect 2 VPC cross-region for the same aws account. [Ref](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-direct-connect-gateway-inter-region-vpc-access/)